# Change Outlook Default PST using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0

I want to do the following using PowerShell.

1. Create a new PST file "Data1.PST"
2. Mark the file "Data1.PST" as default.
3. Delete the original default PST file.

Comment: Did you try anything before posting? if so, please add your code...

Comment: Nice project indeed. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome!  Please read [ask] a good question.  Please keep in mind we are not a free code writing service.  We expect you to try to solve the problem yourself and provide us with code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in PS or Outlook Object Model alone - you need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) or [ProfMan](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) (comes with the distributable version of Redemption).

Redemption - if you are already dealing  with an active Outlook Session. Use [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`Stores.DefaultStore` to open the default store. Use [RDOPstStore](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOPstStore).`PstPath` to figure out the path to the PST file. To add a new PST store, use `RDOSession.Stores.AddPstStore`. You can then change the [RDOStore](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).`Default` property to true.

ProfMan (if you want to manipulate the existing profiles without actually logging in) - see an example at https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#example4. -